# Same task executed multiple times

Tags: python, redis, celery

I have ETA tasks that get sent to a Redis broker for Celery. It is a single celery and redis instance, both int he same machine.

The problem is, tasks are getting executed multiple times. I've seen tasks executed 4 to 11 times.

I set up the visibility timeout to be 12 hours, given that my ETA's are between 4-11 hours (determined at runtime):

```
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': 12 * 60 * 60}
```

Even with that, tasks still get executed multiple times.

Initially, the task in question was not idempotent, so I tried adding in a DB check to make them idempotent.

it looks something like this:

```
@app.task
def foo(side_effect_action):
    if side_effect_action.executed:
        return ALREADY_EXECUTED
    else:
        do_side_effect()
        side_effect_action.executed = True
        side_effect_action.save() #hits the db
        return JUST_EXECUTED
```

Turns out that the celery worker gets to the task before foo is able to call `side_effect_action.save()` and save the state, so in all cases when it's looking for `side_effect_action.executed` it is still False, and thus gets executed multiple times.

Any ideas how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Apparently this is an open issue when using the Redis as broker: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4400

Answer (score 4):

I switched my celery broker to RabbitMQ to avoid this issue. It is unfortunate since I now have one more component in my webapp (I still need redis for something else), but it did solve the multiple execution for ETA tasks bug.