# celery/redis task recieved multiple times rapidly.

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I published two countdown task using django-celery, which must run at `2014-10-15 06:45` and `2014-10-15 08:45`.

here is the log when i run using `--loglevel=INFO`

```
[2014-10-15 03:58:19,885: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@web468.webfaction.com ready.    
[2014-10-15 05:57:08,777: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: mysite.celery.send_session_emails[e34174e2-543d-43aa-a7b0-a32b8be81644] eta:[2014-10-15 06:45:53.701697-04:00]

[2014-10-15 05:57:08,778: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: mysite.celery.send_session_emails[08c7935f-7546-428c-a8c5-1e25e0675b12] eta:[2014-10-15 08:45:53.745062-04:00] 

[2014-10-15 06:45:54,704: INFO/MainProcess] Task mysite.celery.send_session_emails[e34174e2-543d-43aa-a7b0-a32b8be81644] succeeded in 0.683478601277s: None  
<-- Great the task at 6:45 executed correctly...


[2014-10-15 06:58:09,522: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: mysite.celery.send_session_emails[08c7935f-7546-428c-a8c5-1e25e0675b12] eta:[2014-10-15 08:45:53.745062-04:00]
[2014-10-15 07:58:09,711: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: mysite.celery.send_session_emails[08c7935f-7546-428c-a8c5-1e25e0675b12] eta:[2014-10-15 08:45:53.745062-04:00] 
<-- who published there two tasks,, i checked my code and i am sure that i didn't published them   

[2014-10-15 08:45:55,469: INFO/MainProcess] Task mysite.celery.send_session_emails[08c7935f-7546-428c-a8c5-1e25e0675b12] succeeded in 0.410996085964s: None
[2014-10-15 08:45:55,815: INFO/MainProcess] Task mysite.celery.send_session_emails[08c7935f-7546-428c-a8c5-1e25e0675b12] succeeded in 0.345424972009s: None
[2014-10-15 08:45:56,292: INFO/MainProcess] Task mysite.celery.send_session_emails[08c7935f-7546-428c-a8c5-1e25e0675b12] succeeded in 0.47599364398s: None
<-- executed 3 tasks at 8:45, i actually published one at 8:45.
```

---

#### my question is `why did celery automatically published those two tasks? ie`

```
[2014-10-15 06:58:09,522: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: mysite......
[2014-10-15 07:58:09,711: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: mysite........
```

Comment: seems like it is a problem with visibility timeout(The default visibility timeout for Redis is 1 hour), and the task(if not executed) get automatically published again after 1 hour duration. so how can i stop this automatic republishing?

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568354/same-task-executed-multiple-times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I switched my celery broker to `SQLalchemy` to avoid this issue. It solved the multiple execution for ETA tasks bug.

installed **SQLAlchemy** by:

```
pip install SQLAlchemy
```

updated **settings.py**:

```
BROKER_URL='sqla+mysql://<mysql user>:<mysql password>@localhost/<mysql db_name>'
```